# string.search(".") always return 0

Tags: regex, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flashbuilder4

I am work in Flash Builder 4.
Create e-mail validator on Flex.
Have this code

```
    public var s:String="";

    public function checkSumbols(_s:String=""):Boolean {

        s=_s;  //e-mail address (input mail@supermail.com)

        var hDog:int=0; 
        var hPoint:int=0;
        //check @
        hDog=s.search("@");
        trace(hDog)  // It's work
        if(hDog==-1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            hPoint=s.substr(hDog).search(".");
            trace(hPoint); // PANIC this return always 0
            if(hPoint==-1){
               return false;
        }}
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use regex. Since dot (.) has special meaning in regex you need to put 'escape' character before: `yourString.search(/\./);`
Should work.
HTH
FTQuest

Comment: Exactly the same problem, creating email validation function and it got stuck on the period returning 0. This works perfectly!!

Answer (score 2):

search() accepts a pattern, and `.` just means "a single character", so it is probably returning the first single character, which would most likely be at index 0.

You could try `search("\.")`

Comment: mvid check search("\.")-return 0 ((((

Comment: I have never written in flash, but I'd try `search("\\.")`.

Answer (score 0):

I try with search(/[.]/) and it worked well in javascript, I think that It would work in the same mode in as3